# Rstudio like auto indentation in VSCode/Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, indentation

I'm getting into using Julia from usually using R/Rstudio. One of Rstudio's most useful features was its ability to automatically indent code when I press enter while typing out.
E.g. I can press enter after typing out "3," and the end of the vector and it will automatically indent like so:

```
matrix(c(1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6),
       2, 3)
```

Is there a way to replicate this functionality with Julia/VScode?
E.g. type out the following and/or other functions without manually entering spaces

```
array_1 = [1 2 3:
           4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you press `<enter>` after the `[`, all indentation will be automatic thereafter

```
array_1 = [
    1 2 3;
    4 5 6
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you manually indent the second row of the matrix, then subsequent rows will be indented automatically.

[image: automatic matrix indentation]